# Taking a screenshot of a fullscreen DirectX Application in Java

Tags: java, directx, screenshot, fullscreen

I'm fairly positive this is impossible with the default Java library you're given with Eclipse etc. 
I've clicked just about every link related to this search and so many people have the same problem, that is, black or white screenshots etc.

I've tried all the basic methods, robot screencaptures etc. 
I have also looked into Javacv https://code.google.com/p/javacv/ however that's way too heavy duty and requires too many external installments.

I hardly expect this to be simple, are there any guides, tutorials on taking screenshots of directX apps/games?

Comment: Its already nearly impossible to (reliably) use Direct/X in a Java application :s Java was not designed for these kind of operating system specific tasks, this will almost certainly require native code.

Comment: Mmm, as I feared :(

Hopefully someone can help me out.

Comment: Even many non-java applications have problems with DirectX and hardware accelerated videos because the optimizations made for fast rendering must bypass the normal (slow) drawing routines. Try to find a solution that works in some other language (#1 related question does not look bad), then figure out a way to use that from Java.